# installing caffe on Ubuntu 18.04 GPU TitanX CUDA 9.1 CuDNN 7.1 without Anaconda Python 3.6

Tags: python3, cuda, caffe

Having problem installing Caffe on Ubuntu 18.04 GPU TitanX CUDA 9.1 CuDNN 7.1 without Anaconda Python 3.6. Running make -j8 all gets the following error:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libcudnn.so when searching for -lcudnn
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so when searching for -lcudnn
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudnn.so when searching for -lcudnn
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so when searching for -lcudnn
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so when searching for -lcudnn
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so when searching for -lcudnn
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lcudnn
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:583: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I tried providing the directory address to CuDNN (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and usr/local/include for the header) in Makefile.Config. Here is the content of Makefile.Config :

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
# CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0
# This code is taken from https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib
# USE_HDF5 := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA >= 9.0, comment the *_20 and *_21 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := #-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        #-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.6m
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.6m \
                 /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
#WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
#INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial /usr/local/cuda/include  
#LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# NCCL acceleration switch (uncomment to build with NCCL)
# https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl (last tested version: v1.2.3-1+cuda8.0)
# USE_NCCL := 1

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
#USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

# N.B. both build and distribute dirs are cleared on `make clean`
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

I also tried creating symbolic links between libcudnn.so.7.1.2 and libcudnn.so :

```
ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.1.2 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7
```

and between libcudnn.so.7.1.2 and libcudnn.so :

```
ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.1.2 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so
```

Typing `ld -lcudnn --verbose` spits out the following final lines :

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so succeeded
ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so when searching for -lcudnn
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libcudnn.a failed
ld: cannot find -lcudnn
```

I checked where cudnn is (`sudo find / -name libcudnn*so*`) and got the following answer : `/home/meriemlio/Downloads/cuda/targets/ppc64le-linux/lib/libcudnn.so /root/caffe/libcudnn.so find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied find: ‘/run/user/120/gvfs’: Permission denied /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so`

I tried adding directories `ld` isn't checking for `libcudnn` by typing for instance :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I still get the same error. Any clues ?